# Unable to connect to linux machine using hostname(Able to connect using IpAddress using shrapSSH and C sharp)

Tags: c#, linux

I am trying to connect to linux remote machine using hostname it fails(but i am able to connect using Ipaddress) using Shrp SSH as interface . here is my sample code

```
public void ConnectToLinuxParttion()
{
    string username = "aaaa";
    string password = "aaaa";
    string partionName = Lmac;

    try
    {
        SshExec exec = new SshExec(partionName,username,password);
        exec.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
        exec.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Reason for Not Connecting is " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

the errors i am getting are:

> The Reason for Not Connecting is Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.JSchException: 
>    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested name is
>    valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for    at
>   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String
>   hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)    at
>
> System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(String
>   hostName)    at
>
> Tamir.SharpSsh.java.net.Socket..ctor(String
>   host, Int32 port)    at
>
> Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Util.createSocket(String
>   host, Int32 port, Int32 timeout)    at
>
> Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32
>   connectTimeout)    at
>
> Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect() at
>
> Tamir.SharpSsh.SshBase.ConnectSession(Int32 tcpPort)    at
>
> Tamir.SharpSsh.SshBase.Connect(Int32 tcpPort)    at
>
> Tamir.SharpSsh.SshBase.Connect()

Please help regarding this Thanks in acvance

It worked fine when we installed Bonjour Service on our machines and  AVahi on Linux machines add .Local  partionName   they will work only in same subnet address else it wont.

Comment: Hej Anders, did you ever get this issue solved? I am experiencing it too.

Comment: Yes , i was able to solve this . please see my       Answer.